# is there any alternative of Javascript confirm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, confirm

I have created one application. In the application I have used javascript confirm function a lot.

```
confirm("Do you want to proceed");
```

I don't like the default UI of confirm. I want to use customized  confirm with better UI.

**Problem:**

I got some options for customized confirm. But if I will use them I need to change all default confirm methods(needs lot of changes).

Is there any way to achieve this in minimal change.

like:

```
window.confrim = function() {
        /*
           What logic I should write which will return the 
           value(true or false) selected by user.
        */

}
```

I have one JS file which is imported in all HTML files.

So I can place the above function logic in the common JS file.

Comment: _"Is there any way to achieve this in minimal changes."_ No - `window.confirm` is a blocking call, which you can't replicate with any form of styled elements etc.  By all means make a better alternative, but you'll need to update all your calls to `confirm` to use a callback for any following code.

Comment: [sweetalert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/), I think this library will fulfill your needs

Comment: @AdamAzad This isn't modal. I mean OP would still need to replace somehow all his `window.confirm` calls

Comment: Or you could just style your own dialog box, and add scripts that prompts users for input

Comment: @A.Wolff, true, but this is the only way to "customized confirm with better UI." Still, OP needs to consider what James pointed out.

Comment: @AdamAzad Ya then this is a pretty useful plugin

Answer (score 6):

The biggest issue with customising `confirm` is that the native `confirm` is blocking. So you can just write:

```
if( confirm("Continue?")) {
    doStuff();
}
```

But your own code can't do that. Instead, you would need to create some kind of callback. An example might be:

```
myConfirm("Continue?",function() {
    doStuff();
},function() {
    cancelStuff();
});
```

Exactly how you implement this is up to you - I actually have a more flexible version of this on my projects, where I make a call of the form:

```
Dialog("Title", "Contents", [array of buttons]);
// [array of buttons] being an array of objects like:
{
    "text": "Button text",
    "action": function() {doSomething();},
    "optional_extras": "more stuff"
}
```

The cool thing about writing your own stuff is that you can extend it freely to suit your needs as the project grows.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm box is part of the browser not the DOM. So, its not possible to modify that. You can try custom confirm boxes like http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation OR

http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/