# Alternative of confirm() function in js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

Can anyone help with some alternative of confirm() function in JavaScript. In my legacy application this function is working fine in Internet explorer but has stopped working in chrome & Firefox.

Comment: There is no reason for `confirm()` to stop working.

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example so we can help debug. `confirm()` works just fine for me in Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: `alert()`/`confirm()`/`prompt()` [stopped working a while ago for cross-origin iframes in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68492434/javascript-dialogs-alert-confirm-and-prompt-in-cross-origin-iframe-does-n).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there any alternative of Javascript confirm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963696/is-there-any-alternative-of-javascript-confirm)

Comment: you can use an HTML dialog box, you can use the Sweet Alert plugin.